# RSelenium Pop up window

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I am trying to open a popup link within an HTML page:

```
<a class="popup-link" href="/PPI/displayRemarks.do?itemId=100582281" title="Add Remarks for the item" onclick="return false" id="anch_12">Add remarks</a>
```

I tried using the ID to find the element:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'id', "anch_12")
```

I receive this error:

```
Selenium message:{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'anch_12'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/xml, application/xml, /","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Content-Length":"32","Content-Type":"application/json","Host":"localhost:4567","User-Agent":"libcurl/7.56.0 r-curl/3.0 httr/1.3.1"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"anch_12\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c6eac2b0-1bfd-11e8-8fbd-fbf94221e6d1/element"}}
```

Error Summary:

```
NoSuchElement Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` **anch_12** as well as the `href` attribute with value with **itemId=100582281** looks dynamic. Hence you have to construct a dynamic `xpath` as follows :

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//a[@class='popup-link' and contains(@href,'/PPI/displayRemarks.do?itemId=') and starts-with(@id,'anch_')]")
//or
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//a[@class='popup-link' and contains(@title,'Add Remarks for the item') and starts-with(@id,'anch_')]")
```